# exportArchive: No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, azure-devops

working on ionic 4 ios app in azure build pipeline, trying to archive the build and encountered an error

```
2020-07-09 12:17:12.156 xcodebuild[5440:16936] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/myApp_2020-07-09_12-17-12.155.xcdistributionlogs'.
error: exportArchive: No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive

Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive}

##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 70
```

my I checked with my certificates and they are in right place, also I tried running using cmd

```
ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

but no use.

while running pipeline I got a warning as well but didn't found any solution for this. do i need to change something?

```
##[warning]Failed to automatically identify the export method to use from the archive file. This might cause errors during the build or produce an invalid package. If export fails, either enable signing (set `Signing Style` to `Project Defaults`), or configure export manually (set `Export options` to `Plist` or `Specify`).
```

Comment: Are you using self-hosted agent? Which task you used in the pipeline to archive the build, Could you share the task's configuration?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT  yes I am using self-hosted mac agent. I am using xcode task to archive the build.

I fixed this error by setting `Export options` to specify and specified export method as `app-store`  and adding the `Team ID`

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT but now while uploading the ipa from `Publish to the App Store TestFlight track` task, I am getting error `Missing Provisioning Profile - Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision.` and I am not sure how to fix this

Comment: An Xcode app must be signed and provisioned to run on a device or be published to the App Store, Did you sign your app? Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xcode?view=azure-devops#signing-and-provisioning) for more information.

Comment: Yes...I used a resing task in the release pipeline before uploading the .ipa to the app store. As it was not possible for me to sign app in the build pipeline so I decided to build the app without sign and then use the resign task to sign the ipa. and It worked out for me

Comment: That's great it worked out. Could you share out your solution? It might help others who encounter the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Can you please share you solution @RageshPikalmunde?

Comment: @Renascent please read the above comments...will share the solution as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posting solution which worked out for me as  It might help others who encounter the same issue.

I used an `IPA resing task` in the azure release pipeline before uploading the `.ipa` to the app store.

As I couldn't sign the app while building in the build pipeline, I decided to build the unsigned app and then use the `resign task` to sign the `IPA` again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting answer but it would be good if you can share piece of yaml script. So I can understand it better with your example as I am pretty new to iOS and this pipeline stuff.... Thanks

Comment: @LucasBatista there is a task to resign the IPA in the azure DevOps pipeline. you can use that, I have added a picture in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

your `Xcode@5` task is probably missing either of the two attributes:

```
exportOptions: 'specify'
exportTeamId: "Team Id"
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to make use of InstallAppleCertificate@2 and InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1 tasks and specify certificate and provisioning profile which you can generate in apple developer portal

example:

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'development.p12'
    certPwd: ''
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'development.mobileprovision'
```

Comment: I already mentioned that my certificates are in right place. Please read the question carefully.